# How to add data via $.ajax ( serialize() + extra data ) like this

Tags: jquery

I want to add extra data after i use $('#myForm').serialize() + extra data

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'POST',
   url: $('#myForm').attr('action'),
   data: $('#myForm').serialize(),   // I WANT TO ADD EXTRA DATA + SERIALIZE DATA
   success: function(data){
      alert(data);
      $('.tampil_vr').text(data);
   }
});
```

Answer (score 177, accepted):

What kind of data?

```
data: $('#myForm').serialize() + "&moredata=" + morevalue
```

The "data" parameter is just a URL encoded string. You can append to it however you like. See the API [here](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/).

Comment: thanks jthompson it works very well... I see $.ajax manual not serialize() ( newbie in ajax )

Comment: if more then a single data element nees to be added you can consider using `...serialize()+'&'+$.param(myParametersObject)` where myParametersObject is a simple object like `{'param':'val','param2':'val2',...}`

Comment: `serialize` will url-encode the data, so I prefer to let it do the work: `$('#myForm, #moredataid').serialize()`

Answer (score 12):

Personally, I'd append the element to the form instead of hacking the serialized data, e.g.

```
moredata = 'your custom data here';

// do what you like with the input
$input = $('<input type="text" name="moredata"/>').val(morevalue);

// append to the form
$('#myForm').append($input);

// then..
data: $('#myForm').serialize()
```

That way, you don't have to worry about `?` or `&`

Comment: you're serializing a form so why would there ever be a case of ? or &??? It would always be a & unless you're serializing an empty form... `<form id="someForm"></form>` which in turn has no point

Comment: Why should I have to deal with that in the first place? Why not just append the element to the form, then serialize it, cleaner than having to concatenate strings to the serialized form, which the dev could get wrong simply by missing an & or = for each field added.

Comment: Then I would recommend using `.serializeArray()` and appending the data to the array instead. It will post the same either way. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102732/can-i-add-data-to-an-already-serialized-array

Comment: I agree. I just wouldn't want to append items to the serialized string, I'd rather have the jQuery do the hard work.

Answer (score 4):

**You can do it like this:**

```
postData[postData.length] = { name: "variable_name", value: variable_value };
```