# html submit form ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

Im currently loading my pages in Codeigniter using ajax for sections of the page.

but, when i press submit on one of the loaded forms, i dont get the response out from it. *its like the form never was sent. im exspecting the layout to be proccessed, instead it returns the same layout as if it wasnt proccessed.*

How can i make so, when pressing submit button on the loaded form data, that it will be proccessed by the same url, and then load the new response to the view?

piece of code:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
        $(".main_center").html(data);
    });
    return false; // prevent normal submit
});
```

piece of html:

```
<form method="POST" action="/crime">
      <input type="hidden" name="crimeinput" id="crimeAction" value="123">
                    <input type="submit" value="do" name="docrime" id="krimsubmit" style="display:none">
</form>
```

EDIT:

**After more looking into it, it seems like only the crimeInput variable is sent to the server, and not the docrime. How can i make it able to send the submit name aswell?**

Comment: Is the name your url?

Comment: added piece of code @aldrin27

Comment: What is `action='crime'`?

Comment: it is a page, on my site.

Comment: You declared two ajax. The first one that is submitting the form and the next one is inside your function.

Comment: What is inside the hidden? And you can't pass the submit on your ajax.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89559/discussion-between-maria-and-aldrin27).

Answer (score 1):

As per the docs for [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/):

> Note: Only "successful controls" are serialized to the string. **No**
> **submit button value is serialized since the form was not submitted
> using a button.** For a form element's value to be included in the
> serialized string, the element must have a name attribute. Values from
> checkboxes and radio buttons (inputs of type "radio" or "checkbox")
> are included only if they are checked. Data from file select elements
> is not serialized.

So if you want that field to be passed, you'll have to add it in a different way, perhaps as another hidden input.

Comment: so there is no way for me to somehow send the button values aswell? cause i have alot of pages that depends on this.

Comment: You could add like I said above, or manually. Check out this question/answer http://stackoverflow.com/q/4406348/1301076