# Serialize form and attach a list of strings to it

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I'm trying to serialise my form, but for some reason I can't make it work. The serialisation of the form is working. But the issue is, that I'll need to add a list **afterwards**, since it's not a part of the form, and when doing this my model is NULL when it's hitting my controllers endpoint.

```
        var valdata = $("#CreateForm").serialize();  

        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#productCheckbox:checked');
        var checkedElements = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function (el, i) {
            return el.name;
        });

        if (checkedElements.length == 0) {
            alert('You must select at least one product');
            return
        }

        var data = {
            model: valdata,
            products: checkedElements
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Product/Create',
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
            },
            error: function (data) {
                console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
            }
        });
```

The function of the Controller I'm hitting:

```
public ActionResult Create(Model model, object products)
```

The object products is working fine, but the model is `null`.

Do anyone have any suggestions, how to fix this? :-)

Please don't mind the name of the objects like Model, this is named something else in our project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a demo:

Model:

```
public class Model 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

View:

```
<form id="CreateForm">
    <input name="Id" />
    <input name="Name" />
    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="postdata()" />
</form>
<input type="checkbox" id="productCheckbox" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
<label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="productCheckbox" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
<label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label>
<br>
<input type="checkbox" id="productCheckbox" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
<label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label>
<br>
```

js(I convert form data to a model):

```
<script>
        function postdata(){
            var valdata = $("#CreateForm").serializeArray();
            var returnModel = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < valdata.length; i++) {
                returnModel[valdata[i]['name']] = valdata[i]['value'];
            }
            

        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('#productCheckbox:checked');
        var checkedElements = Array.prototype.map.call(elements, function (el, i) {
        return el.name;
        });

        if (checkedElements.length == 0) {
        alert('You must select at least one product');
        return
        }

        var data = {
        model: returnModel,
        products: checkedElements
        };

        $.ajax({
        url: '/Test/Create',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
        console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
        },
        error: function (data) {
        console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(data))
        }
        });
        }
    </script>
```

result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "data" parameter is just a URL encoded string. You can append to it however you like.

For Example:

```
data: $('#myForm').serialize() + "&moredata=" + morevalue
```

Check the below link for more details.

[Click here for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4406348/how-to-add-data-via-ajax-serialize-extra-data-like-this/15836323)